# How to wait until element is updated with latest/actual text of it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In the application which I'm automating, I've a case where for an element I've to get a text and compare it.

When driver gets text of an element(`driver.findElement(locator).getText()`), it returns - `0` but within a second or two after that it returns actual value for that element. It could be `4`, `10` or something else.

If I use `Thread.sleep(2000)` and then retrieve it doesn't return `0` It returns actual value of it.

I don't want to use sleep hence I tried `document.readyState`, `jQuery.active` but no luck.

Is there a best way which will wait until the value of the element is updated with actual?

Comment: you can assign value to new variable and observe that new variable is set or not..? this may work.......

Comment: That will solve it but how long to wait? I'll have to use sleep there.

Answer (score 0):

In C# I would call something like this. It would wait until getText returns a value that isn't 0 or throw a timeout expception after 10 seconds if it doesn't change before continuning. You can modify that take    driver.findElement(locator).getText() if you wish instead of     element.getText.

```
 public void WaitForElementValue(IWebElement element, string intialValue)
    {
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        wait.Until<bool>((d) =>
            {
                if (element.getText != intialValue)
                    return true;
                else return false;
            });
    }
```

Comment: For my current case, we know that iniitial text for the element is `0` but there are so many such elements, I don't want to write for that many times. I would like to have a generic way for this.